# What is the SystemColors of the Textbox's border?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What is the SystemColors of the Textbox's border?

Comment: need to be more specific

Comment: I guess it would depend on the BorderStyle of the textbox as well as your system's theme settings.

Comment: BorderStyle is Fixed3D, for now I settle for SystemColors.WindowFrame, but it's not exactly the border color of the textbox

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955597/wpf-systemcolors-color-of-textbox-border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set it in your code, don't use the SystemColors, use the VisualStyleInformation.TextControlBorder instead (look it up in MSDN).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases (XP, Vista, Windows 7) - there is no correpsonding value. The text box is rendered by the Theme in use. When no theme is used - it uses the ControlLight and ControlDark values to render the 3D sunken border.