# Can TextBox selection be styled with a different font color?

Tags: wpf, textbox, styling

Styling is a big feature of WPF. Surely it's possible to make a text box look exactly like the OS textbox?

I'm tired of the bleak desaturated color that the selection must have in order for the black text to be visible:

[image: textbox selection comparison]

Is this fixable?

Comment: If you can figure out a way to fix *all* of the WPF controls to look and behave exactly like the native OS controls, then you might really have something!

Comment: @CodyGray That's a dream... Kind of opposite to what WPF seems to have been architected to do in some misguided effort, eh?...

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's one of the reasons why I haven't been persuaded to switch to WPF. I don't have any special reason to try and make my applications uglier, slower, and harder to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **.NET 4.8** you can now set the AppContext flag `UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering` to false

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.Windows.Controls.Text.UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering=false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And then use the new property `SelectionTextBrush` to achieve this like

```
<TextBox Text="Test WPF TextBox"
         SelectionBrush="#1174E6"
         SelectionTextBrush="White"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately it might be impossible, the selection highlighting is done via an overlaying rectangle (brilliant idea, isn't it?), this makes it hard to even get the selection background-color you want while retaining text readablility. (Try setting `SelectionOpacity` to `1`)

Also the selected text portion does not appear to be styled so changing the foreground colour of the selection is not easily possible either.

Comment: My god you're right. Who came up with that?... The contrast is already low, and it turns out the text isn't even fully black!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need the [`SelectionBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionbrush.aspx)? It's a dependency property. (Not sure if it's available in .NET version < 4).

For finding what the current system colors are, you can use [`SystemColors` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx).

See an example here: [WPF SystemColors: color of TextBox border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955597/wpf-systemcolors-color-of-textbox-border).

Comment: The selection brush is already of the correct color. If I set the opacity to 1, then selected text becomes completely invisible. So no, this doesn't help.

Comment: @romkyns: Well, why not make the color _darker_ in this case? If you need color X, but your opacity is 50%, try X/2.

Comment: Firstly, because it's impossible to achieve `0x3399FF` as a result of a 50% blend of _any_ color against white (try it - you need a negative red for that to work), and secondly, because even if it was achievable, black text is not very readable against that shade of blue.