# WPF .Net Core SelectionTextBrush doesnt work

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, xaml, highlight

I am trying to have a richtextbox and when i highlight the text, i want it to change to a different color. It seems to have worked in .Net Framework 4.8, as the solution is provided here:

[Can TextBox selection be styled with a different font color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801554/can-textbox-selection-be-styled-with-a-different-font-color/68096361#68096361)

However, this cannot be applied to .NET Core 7 and is not working in my WPF application.
Is there a workaround or fix that can make highlighted text appear in a different color? This seems to be a bug in Microsoft .Net Core and they dont seem to have a fix yet. So i need a workaround where highlighed text will change to a different color.

I have tried the following
[Can TextBox selection be styled with a different font color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801554/can-textbox-selection-be-styled-with-a-different-font-color/68096361#68096361)

I believe this worked in .Net Framework but NOT in .Net Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.setswitch?view=net-7.0#examples), the configuration of `.Net Core` is different from `.Net Framework`.

In you WPF(.net core) application, you need to set `Switch.System.Windows.Controls.Text.UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering` to `false` in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Windows.Controls.Text.UseAdornerForTextboxSelectionRendering", false);
    }
}
```

Then add a `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="Test WPF TextBox"
         SelectionBrush="#1174E6"
         SelectionTextBrush="Red"/>
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you buddy. This works. Although I was using RichTextBox and it still doesnt work there. At least i modified the TextBox to work like a RickTextBox, so yes, thanks, its workijng now.