# How can I set properties of WPF controls with replaced ControlTemplate at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I've got a number of TextBoxes which are generated at run-time. I would like to set their border brush colour to green when a certain action is carried out, as well as change the border thickness. This has to be done from the code-behind in my case.

My first challenge was to stop the TextBox borders from changing colour when hovered over with the mouse. This was accomplished by adding this style:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                        <Border 
          Name="Border"
          Padding="1"
          Background="#FFFFFF"
          BorderBrush="#888888"
          BorderThickness="1" >
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewWithLines}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,5,0,5"/>
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="true"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TreeView Name="tvFilters" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="White" BorderBrush="White"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

The above code is for my UserControl.

Next, a new problem started arising. Whenever I attempt to change the BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties manually within a code behind method, absolutely nothign happens. This is the code:

```
txt.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
txt.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You just asked this question, didn't you?  I searched and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955597/wpf-systemcolors-color-of-textbox-border).

Comment: Please edit the title to the real question.

Comment: `WPF Frustrations` - WPF has no frustrations. You're using WPF in a winforms way. That's the cause of your frustrations.

Comment: `I've got a number of TextBoxes which are generated at run-time` - This is not winforms. You need an `ItemsControl` or any derivatives for that.

Comment: Also, DO NOT subclass WPF controls unless you have a GOOD reason to.

Comment: `This has to be done from the code-behind in my case.` - Almost nothing has to be done from code behind in WPF. Rethink your approach.

Comment: @gdoron I don't care about downvotes, winforms still sucks and will suck forever even if I have -2487249827498 score on Stackoverflow.

Comment: You do realise that you can't downvote comments right?

Comment: @gdoron - Much like HighCore said in his response, I don't mind downvotes.  When a question is asked, I think I may know the answer, I respond after doing research on my own.  If I don't know, I don't respond.  The is an old addage I truly love, "Better to be silent and be thought a fool, than to open your mouth and remove all doubt."

Comment: @HighCore - I don't agree that Winforms sucks, but maybe I will after I get used to WPF. I've only just started working with it. Thanks for pointing out that I'm not using it properly, I'll be sure to read up on it :) It's just so vast that it's hard to decide where to start from without diving right into it

Comment: @Dotnet That's right. There's huge mindshift needed when switching from winforms to WPF. [Reed Copsey wrote an excellent series of articles on this](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/07/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm/). And yes, winforms actually sucks a lot.

Comment: The main problem is that the project I'm working on has been written in WPF, in a WinForms way as you pointed out. And due to time constraints it would be too much of an overhead to arrange the whole project completely

Comment: @DotNet Yeah, I have the same problem in our project. I'm slowly refactoring the entire project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as the control template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
     <Border 
      Name="Border"
      Padding="1"
      Background="#FFFFFF"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EEEEEE"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

You can probably guess by comparing the two: you are hard coding the values of the `Border` which is generated for the `TextBox` visual subtree. The way to handle this is to bind the property value of the visual to the value of the property of the control. `TemplateBinding` was created to do this.

Also, note, while I've provided you the answer, you're not really using WPF in a way which takes best advantage of its design. Generating controls at runtime is best done using a `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It *almost* works. Only issue now is that by default the textbox is not showing. Is its border set to white?

Comment: I'd guess it's the triggers you have on the `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: Maybe it's the: Background="#FFFFFF"

Comment: It's probably getting the default style which is also the same as the window color, making it appear invisible. Try changing the Background color instead of just removing it.

Comment: Actually changing the BorderThickness to 1 helped :) So problem is solved. Thanks for helping! +1